# Removing records based on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

What I'm trying to do is taking these records that looks like this:

```
    Name    Enrollment_Month    Premium
    John    20201201            $76.00 
    John    20201201            $54.00
    Tony    20201201            $20
```

and change it to look like this:

```
Name    Enrollment_Month    Premium
Tony    20201201            $20
```

Basically trying to remove both records where name and enrollment month are the same.

Any thought, I would be really appreciate it

Comment: Do you want to query the table and not have these records removed, or do you want to delete them from the table?

Comment: I want to delete them from the table

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
delete from t
   where exists (select 1
                 from t t2
                 where t2.name = t.name and
                       t2.enrollment_month = t.enrollment_month and
                       t2.rowid <> t.rowid
                );
```

Note:  This will delete rows where there are 2 *or more*.  If you specifically want only pairs deleted:

```
delete from t
   where 2 = (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.enrollment_month = t.enrollment_month 
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `HAVING` clause to determine duplicates whenever `GROUP`ed `BY` those columns(`enrollment_month`, `name`) such as

```
DELETE t
 WHERE (enrollment_month, name) IN
       (SELECT enrollment_month, name
          FROM t
         GROUP BY enrollment_month, name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function to identify duplicate records and delete them based on `rowid` as follows:

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE T.ROWID IN (
   SELECT CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ENROLLMENT_MONTH, NAME) > 1 
            THEN ROWID 
          END AS ROWIDS
        FROM YOUR_TABLE)
```